# Table in Keynote with booktabs style

Tags: keynote, text, formatting

When creating tables in Keynote, is there a way to create them with the [booktabs style](https://texblog.org/2017/02/06/proper-tables-with-latex/) of typesetting?

For those not familiar with booktabs, an example table looks like this:

[image: booktabs example]

```
-----------------------------------------------
                  Treatment A   Treatment B
-----------------------------------------------
 John Smith            1             2
 Jane Doe              -             3
 Mary Johnson          4             5
-----------------------------------------------
```

The key points are:

- No vertical lines (e.g., between columns).
- Only three horizontal lines (at the top, bottom, and immediately below the headings), but we don't have horizontal lines between every pair of rows.

I realize I could create a table in external software (e.g., LaTeX), then export to PDF or PNG and import as a PDF or PNG.  However, that wouldn't achieve consistency of style with the rest of the Keynote presentation, and is more work.

Is there a way to achieve this formatting style within Keynote?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create the table and then click on the Format button in the top right-hand corner of the keynote page. In the right sidebar, you have 4 tabs one of which says Cells. Click on the Cells tab and you can define the colors or styles of the lines in the table or select no lines between cells or rows of cells. See the table I created in Keynote below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can see how to eliminate all lines, but I can't see how to add the three horizontal lines mentioned in my question (at the top, bottom, and immediately below the headings).  Are you able to figure out how to do that?